# you don't have permission to access / on this server. apache 2.4

Tags: apache, vhosts, hosts, apache2.4

I'm having the problem

> you don't have permission to access / on this server. apache 2.4

while accessing my local web site. I already googled a lot and read a lot of posts here in StackOverflow and everything seems to be correct.

This is my apache version:

> Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix)

Attached my httpd.conf file.
Here is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.smatchme.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/samuelrabini/Project/SmatchMe/smatchme.web"
ServerName localhost.smatchme.com

<Directory /Users/samuelrabini/Project/SmatchMe/smatchme.web>
    Require all granted
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost.smatchme.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost.smatchme.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.piuproduct.com
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/piuproduct/public"
ServerName localhost.piuproduct.com

<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/piuproduct>
    Require all granted
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost.piuproduct.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost.piuproduct.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.b2b.com
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/b2b.tony"
ServerName localhost.b2b.com

<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/b2b.tony>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost.b2b.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost.b2b.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
I'm trying to access my site via http://localhost.b2b.com/

And I added in the /etc/hosts the entry:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.b2b.com
```

thanks in advance
Samuel

Comment: File/directory permissions? Any other sections in the server config that might apply to this directory? What file are you expecting to be served? What files do you have in this directory? .htaccess?

Comment: folder has 777, the web server has an index.php and also the .htaccess. The problem is present after the update from Sierra (php 5.6 and apache 2.2) to High Sierra (php 7.1 and apache 2.4). On Sierra everything was working fine.

Comment: What is in your htaccess file in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/b2b.tony` what dose the log file tell you?

Comment: Here is the htaccess `#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`
the index.php should be executed inside the main folder